# cannot run strict.pm inside su for perl installation

Tags: 16.04, perl, postgresql

I am trying to setup Postgres for a project. In the instructions it says to run `psql`:

```
$ psql
Can't locate strict.pm:   /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/strict.pm: Permission denied at /usr/bin/psql line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/psql line 19.
```

Just running it without `$ sudo su - postgres`, strict.pm works perfectly fine, but when I switch user to postgres, which is required for auth into Postgres, it fails!
Any hacky workarounds are welcome, I just need to be able to get into Postgres and create my user, so I can use it in Diesel inside my project.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In my case reason was PERL5LIB, pointing to HOME directory of another user:

```
postgres@delly:~$ echo $PERL5LIB
/home/sveta/build/mysql-sandbox/share/perl/5.22.1:
```

After setting it to empty string psql started working:

```
postgres@delly:~$ psql
Can't locate strict.pm:   /home/sveta/build/mysql-sandbox/share/perl/5.22.1/strict.pm: Permission denied at /usr/bin/psql line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/psql line 19.
postgres@delly:~$ echo $PERL5LIB
/home/sveta/build/mysql-sandbox/share/perl/5.22.1:
postgres@delly:~$ export PERL5LIB=
postgres@delly:~$ echo $PERL5LIB

postgres@delly:~$ psql
psql (9.5.10)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Comment: This is the only fix I could find that worked.  Thanks, I hope this gets more views.